# Update oracle database using value selected from dropdown in php

Tags: php, html, forms, oracle

In my form,

1. I'm fetching value from the database, based on the input and display it in a dropdown.
2. Now, using a selected value from the dropdown I want to update the database with a preassigned query.

So far, I'm able to fetch the data in the dropdown. But I'm not able to update the db using the selected value. When I submit, I do not see any errors but the database is not updated. I'm new to PHP, not familiar with all the functions. This is the code below:

```
<?php

    $conn = oci_connect("XXX", "XX", "XX");
    if (!$conn)
    {
        $m = oci_error();
        echo $m['message'], "\n";
        exit;
    }

    $query = "SELECT ORDERS_ID,TRACKING_NUMBER
                FROM TABLE
                WHERE ORDERS_ID = :order_bv";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    if (isset($_POST['order']))
    {
        $order = $_POST['order'];
    }
    //$row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC);

    /* if (!$row) {
    //include ('error_page.php');
    exit("The order " . $order . " is invalid. Please check and try again" );
    } */


    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':order_bv', $order);
    oci_execute($stid);


    if (isset($_POST['UpdateTR']))
    {
        $conn2 = oci_connect("XXX", "XX", "XX");
        if (!$conn2)
        {
            $m = oci_error();
            echo $m['message'], "\n";
            exit;
        }


        $query2 = "UPDATE TABLE
                     SET SHIP_TO_STR_DLVR_STATUS='Y'
                     WHERE TRACKING_NUMBER = :updTR_bv";
        $stid2 = oci_parse($conn2, $query2);
        $updTR = $_POST['updTR'];

        oci_bind_by_name($stid2, ':updTR_bv', $updTR);
        oci_execute($stid2, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

        oci_free_statement($stid2); 
        oci_close($conn2);

    }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Form</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body class="blurBg-false" style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
      <!-- Start Formoid form-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="form-solid-blue.css" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
         <div class="title">
            <h2></h2>
            <h2>Tracking & Receiving</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="element-input">
            <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <input class="small" type="text" name="store" placeholder="Store #"/>
               <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="element-input">
            <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <input class="medium" type="text" name="userid" placeholder="UserId"/>
               <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="element-input">
            <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <input class="large" type="text" name="order" placeholder="Order Number"/>
               <span class="icon-place"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send"/>
         </div>
         <div class="element-separator">
            <hr>

            <h3 class="section-break-title">Tracking Numbers</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="element-multiple">
            <label class="title"></label>
            <div class="item-cont">
               <div class="large">

                 <?php 
                    echo  '<select data-no-selected="Nothing selected" name="updTR"  multiple="no">';


                    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) 
                    { 
                        $data[] = $row; 
                    }
                    foreach ($data as $value)
                    {
                        //echo "<option value=\"option_1\">" . $value['TRACKING_NUMBER'] . "</option>";
                        echo "<option value="<?php $value['TRACKING_NUMBER']; ?>"><?php echo $value['TRACKING_NUMBER']; ?></option>";
                        //echo "selected = 'selected'";                       
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    oci_free_statement($stid); 
                    oci_close($conn);

                  ?>   

                  <span class="icon-place"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="UpdateTR" value="Submit"/>
         </div>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="formoid-solid-blue.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```